# Can i listen to an event in class A which is fired in aSyncTask, without implementing interface in class A?

Tags: android, events, android-asynctask, event-handling, event-listener

First of all i will apologize for the bad question formulation, i don't know how to ask is on a more clear way, so suggestions are welcome!

I'm new with android and struggled a lot with aSyncTask for getting some XML from the web. Downloading the XML and pass it to the class who invoked the aSyncTask works fine now.

The problem i have is that i only can listen to the event which is fired in the aSyncTask > onPostExecute method when i put "implements Interface" on the class who invokes the aSyncTask class. I'm interessed to an way where i dont need to implement the interface. I think this is posible becouse the default objects such as buttons and so on can be listened to witouth implementing something.

Maybe i think completely wrong about this all?

The way i set up my own event handler/listener is:

Creating an listener

```
public interface XmlUpdateListener {
   void onXmlUpdate(String result);
}
```

Invoke the listerner in the aSyncTask class

```
public XmlManager(XmlUpdateListener delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    delegate.onXmlUpdate(result);
}
```

Listen to the event in the class who invokes the aSyncTask class

```
public class XmlDataLayer implements XmlUpdateListener 

@Override
public void onXmlUpdate(String result)
{
    this.XML = result;
}
```

I searched for a lot of videos on youtube and a lot of articles on the internet. There are many many ways explained but i don't realy understand one completely. Here on stackoverflow i found a lot of articles but the most of them has no 100% clear answere for me. Maybe someone has a lot of patience to make me this whole stuff clear for ever by give me some sample code and explain me what happened. I'm a person i need to know how it works and why it works like that, then i understand it else it is a big mess in my head and can't still understand.

**---------- Edit: Added some extra info about my problem ----------**

My problem is: from UI i call an dataclass, this gets starts the aSyncTask and get its response over the upstanding mechanism. From there i need to trow an event that can be used on several places. I will catch this event for updating the UI and updating the internal database. The problem is that my UI class extends the AppCompatActivity and i cant implement the interface there to catch the event. That's the reason why i need to catch an event without implementing something. I think something like new XmlManager(..).exe(); looks good but cant get it done without "implements XmlUpdateListener"

Comment: Whats the real problem here? The callback mechanism you employed seems fine.

Comment: what's exactly the issue ?

Comment: As with the other comments, it seems like you have the right mechanism. `(new XmlManager(yourXmlUpdaterListener)).execute();`... You can have your listener operate in the class that calls it.

Comment: Is the question "Why am I passing my clas as an `XmlUpdateListener` and not just my class?"

Comment: I did not quite understand the question but i think you may be looking to initialize and use an anonymous async task directly from your XmlDataLayer?  You can do something like within your class: 

`new AsyncTask<X,Y,Z>{`

     `public Y doInBackground(X ... x){ ... }`
     `public void onPostExecute(Z x){ //your callback code within`     `XmlDataLayer }` 
`}'`

Comment: My problem is: from UI i call an dataclass, this gets starts the aSyncTask and get its response over the upstanding mechanism. From there i need to trow an event that can be used on several places. I will catch this event for updating the UI and updating the internal database. The problem is that my UI class extends the AppCompatActivity and i cant implement the interface there to catch the event. That's the reason why i need to catch an event without implementing something. I think something like new XmlManager(..).exe(); looks good but cant get it done without "implements XmlUpdateListener"